# test for internet connection in android login

Tags: android

I want to check internet connection. I tried to do this using this code but it doesn't work. I didn't got any message (Aucune connexion internet)

```
private boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context applicationContext){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else
            return true;

    }
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if(isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext()))   {
                showEmployee(s);
                }else{
                    // show alert
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aucune connexion internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you fetching the `String s` from the Internet and is this why you are using the `AsyncTask`? In that case, you should check `isConnectingToInternet` *before* running the `AsyncTask`, not inside it.

In any case, try this in your `isConnectingToInternet`:

```
private boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context applicationContext){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Comment: I got this error cannot resolve symbol activeNetworkInfo so I tried to use return ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting(); but there's no message also

Comment: Sorry for that slip, @LaraFab! I corrected it. Can you tell me why you are calling `isConnectingToInternet` inside `onPostExecute`, and what is the parameter `String s` that is passed into `onPostExecute`?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right tracks, but missing 1 tiny part, checking `isConnected` along with `!= null` like this:

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return ((activeNetworkInfo != null) && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

This function works for me. It's only different in that one additional condition from yours.